# Redireccionar usuario a página específica wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

estoy armando una web con elementor pro en wordpress, y tengo el problema que al usar mensaje emergente de logout, al poner la opción redireccionar luego de logout y escribir la url específica, siempre me termina redireccionando al home de la web. En inspección de objetos de chrome, me sale una url redirec to (seguido de la url al que quiero que redireccione y acompañado de wpnonce y la url home de la web). Es posible forzar de alguna manera que me redireccione a la url que quiero?

Answer (score 0):

Pueder redirigir a la página que quieras añadiendo una función en functions.php.

Esta función redigirá al usuario a la página que quieras después de hacer cerrar sesión.

```
//redirect after logout
function auto_redirect_after_logout(){
  wp_redirect('https://www.ejemplo.com');
  exit;
}
add_action('wp_logout','auto_redirect_after_logout');
```

Añade tu url y copia directamente el código en el archivo functions.php de tu tema.